# How to extract row names as a variable in order for it to applied to another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm a newbie to R. I'm currently working with two dataframes, one containing initial values, and another containing values that have been computed using the original data.

My new dataframe for the computed values is built like this:

```
reldf <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 13, nrow = nrow(glasgow2001)))
names <- c("2001r","2002r","2003r","2004r","2005r","2006r","2007r","2008r",
       "2009r","2010r","2011r","2012r","2013r")
```

However, in order to remerge the computed values with the original dataframe, I want to be able to extract the original row names from the first data frame and apply them to this one. And this is where I'm completely lost.

Basically, how do I extract row names in R and apply them onto a new dataframe?

Comment: To get rownames of the dataframe you can use `rownames(df)` where `df` is the name of your dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign column names with names()

```
row.names(reldf) <- names
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not the column names I'm looking to extract from the previous dataframe, it's the row names (each row has an individual code at the beginning)

Comment: You can use row.names(reldf) at the same way

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a shot!